# Jquery Autocomplete not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using jquery autocomplete.In my case I have multiple autocomplete textbox and hidden field on my page.
e.g

```
<input  class='myclass' type='text'> </input>
<input class='.emp_num_hidden' type='hidden'> </input>
<input  class='myclass' type='text'> </input>
<input class='.emp_num_hidden' type='hidden'> </input>
```

and so on...

so when I fire change event on hidden field then it is raised multiple time
below is my code:

```
$(".myclass").each(function() {

var $empName= $(this);
var $empNumber = $empName.next('input:hidden');
//things to do
//Setting variable e.g url...

 $empName.autocomplete(url,{

//code...

}).result(function(event,data,formatted)
{
 $empNumber.val(formatted).change();
});
});
```

In above code $empNumber holds the hidden field which is used to store autocomplete value i.e in this case when 
we select any text from autocomplete then that selected employees number will get store in hidden field.
Based on this hidden field value I want to do ajax call which will return full details of the employee based on his 
employee number.
So I have written hanldler to change event of the hidden field as below.

```
$(.emp_num_hidden).on('change',function (

)};
```

here 'emp_num_hidden' is the class of the hidden field.

Please suggest how can I prevent multiple event on hidden field change.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using the `$(this)` object. Since the `change` event has a target, it will only be effecting one element. The callback function is being executed on this element, `this`. For example:

```
$(".emp_num_hidden").on('change', function (e){
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

What will happen is that an alert window will be shown when the hidden field is changed, containing the employee number from only that hidden field. You will also notices there are a few fixes to your code.

Personally, I would make use of both `id` and `class` attributes on your objects. This gives you wide scope and narrow scope to your selectors.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<input class='myclass' type='text' id='entry-txt-1' />
<input class='emp_num_hidden' type='hidden' id='hide-txt-1' />
<input class='myclass' type='text' id='entry-txt-2' />
<input class='emp_num_hidden' type='hidden' id='hide-txt-2' />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
  var $empName, $empNumber;

  $(".myclass").each(function(key, el) {
    $empName= $(el);
    $empNumber = $empName.next("input[type='hidden']");
    // things to do
    // Setting variable e.g url...
    $empName.autocomplete(url, {
      //code...
    }).result(function(e, d, f){
      $empNumber.val(f).change();
    });
  });
  $(".emp_num_hidden").on('change', function(e){
    var empId = $(this).attr("id");
    var $employeeNumberField = $("#" + empId);
    // Do the needful...
  });
});
```

Taking this a bit further, you may want to consider making use of data attributes. You may also want to look at `select` event for Autocomplete. Something like:

```
$(function(){
  $(".myclass").autocomplete({
    source: url,
    select: function(e, ui){
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);
      $(this).data("emp-number", ui.item.value);
      $.post("employeedata.php", { n: ui.item.value }, function(data){
        $("#empData").html(data);
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

This assumes that `url` returns an array objects with `label` and `value` properties. This would add the Employee Number as a `data-emp-number` attribute to the field that the user was making a selection from. The `label` being their Employee Name, and the `value` being their Employee Number. You could also use this callback to show all the other employee data based on Employee Number.

A working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/zmevd0r0/

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But I did not understand here how using $this will prevent event firing multiple times?   In my hidden field change handler I have already used this object as you mentioned but still change event fires multiple times. Is there any event binding issue?

Comment: I'm using jquery  autocomplete 1.0 version I didn't find enough documentation for how to implement select event in that. Do you know any sources for this?

Comment: @Shubh's you did not specify in your post that you were using something specific. My example makes use of jQeury 3.1.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1. If possible, I would make use of a more recent version of jQuery UI. I do not have a way to test with your version. Please edit and update your post with the versions of jQuery and jQuery UI that you are using so that I can update my answer.

Comment: I do not see Autocomplete being a part of jQuery UI 1.0. The oldest docs I see are for v1.8: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/autocomplete/ Please clarify what you mean by  'autocomplete 1.0'